# Use binding to change usercontrol in a grid

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, user-controls

I'm creating a WPF application, which has a main screen in which other screens are loaded.

The main screen can be seen as a header/footer template where the central part is replaced depending on what I need to show at that moment. (It's a 3 row grid where the `usercontrol` should be put in row 1). This has a `viewmodel` that is changing header/footer status.

I have implemented those changing parts (row 1) as usercontrols.

Now I am wondering if there is any way to use binding (to something..) so that I can change the loaded `usercontrol` and not do it from code behind as I'm doing it now.

If this is going completely against MVVM principles, please give me hints on how I should handle this.

Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds to me like you should be looking at using WPF's DataTemplates.

Take this example XAML based on your question:

```
<Grid>
    ... XAML for your Header and Footer
    <ContentPresenter Content="{Binding MainContent">
        <ContentPresenter.Resources>
            <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type viewmodel:UserControlViewModel}">
                <view:UserControlView>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ContentPresenter.Resources>
    </ContentPresenter>
</Grid>
```

Here I'm using a ContentPresenter to act as a placeholder for your content. This is bound to a property called `MainContent` on your main viewmodel. In your viewmodel, you could then set the MainContent to be the viewmodel for your usercontrol.

The `ContentPresenter` will attempt to display whatever object it is bound to. In this example, I've created a DataTemplate that maps a specific object type (e.g. UserControlViewModel) to a view (e.g. UserControlView).

You can define multiple DataTemplates, to allow your content presenter to handle multiple viewmodels (or any type of object):

```
<Grid>
    ... XAML for your Header and Footer
    <ContentPresenter Content="{Binding MainContent">
        <ContentPresenter.Resources>
            <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type viewmodel:UserControlViewModel}">
                <view:UserControlView>
            </DataTemplate>
            <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type viewmodel:AnotherUserControlViewModel}">
                <view:AnotherUserControlView>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ContentPresenter.Resources>
    </ContentPresenter>
</Grid>
```

I hope that points you in the right direction.

You can find out more info on Data Templating on MSDN:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742521(v=vs.110).aspx

EDIT: It's worth mentioning that you **COULD** just new-up your UserControl.xaml in your main viewmodel, and set that to the MainContent property. No DataTemplate would be required there, as the ContentPresenter knows how to present a UserControl. However, this goes against MVVM, as you're tightly coupling your UI (XAML) with your code (viewmodel).

Comment: Your last point is directly what I'm working with now. I've devised a way to use a `DialogHelper` that instantiates a `CustomDialogView : Window`. The contents of that dialog window could be one of any 3 (or more) `UserControl`s. So instead of queuing the user control in the ViewModel (as I'm doing now), I could use a string and have all the user controls in the `Window.Resources`. How does that sounds? I've just gotta figure out how to do that.